# Is there a way of automatically ordering a group of clickCount's

Tags: javascript, html, click-counting

In my coding that will follow I have 3 clickCounts all vertical  and I am wondering whether there is such code to automatically move the highest clickCount up to the top:

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script type="text/javascript">

function countClicks() {
var x = 0;


x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting" ).innerHTML = x;

var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
if(x>=clickLimit) {

            }
else
{
    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function countClicks1() {
var x = 0;


x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting1" ).innerHTML = x;

var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
if(x>=clickLimit) { 

            }
else
{
    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}
}


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function countClicks2() {
var x = 0;


x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting2" ).innerHTML = x;

var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
if(x>=clickLimit) { 

            }
else
{
    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}
}


</script>


</head>
<body>

<div style="margin-left:100px;">
<img src="../Pictures/BWS + L.A +KUSH/Game.RED_Album_Cover.jpg" alt="red album"><br>
<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks();" />
<div id="counting"></div>

<img src="../Pictures/BWS + L.A +KUSH/Game.RED_Album_Cover.jpg" alt="red album"><br>
<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks1();" />
<div id="counting1"></div>

<img src="../Pictures/BWS + L.A +KUSH/Game.RED_Album_Cover.jpg" alt="red album"><br>
<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks2();" />
<div id="counting2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: PS I'd really recommend refactoring the code; it's 3x the size it needs to be, which is a cognitive barrier. Also, removing unnecessary code (like the CSS here) and whitespaces, and proper indentation, goes a *long* way in helping other people help you.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM can be manipulated by arbitrary criteria. If you wrap each section with an appropriately-id'd div (or span), you can remove it from one place and put it in another like normal. If it's an ordered list, IMO, it should live within an actual ordered list, although that's not strictly necessary, it's just more semantic.